# Split pane on mobile application, does bottom pane have to take up whole screen

Tags: interaction-design, touch-screen, mobile-application, prototype

I'm currently developing a UI for a tablet application (portrait view)

The client asked us to split the application into two panes, where the left side is a preview pane, and the right side gives the user a gallery of shopping items to "drag and drop" into the cart (i.e. drag the actual item into the cart icon).

**Left side:**

[image]

**Right side:**

[image]

As I developed the idea further, I thought about the possibility of including a bottom pane with additional icons (Home, Explore, Profile, Cart) on the left side. But when I tried, it did not look like the user can drag and drop their item into the Cart icon anymore. Furthermore, the whole thing just doesn't look right... so can I ask what the conventions are for this on tablet applications? I know that on mobile apps, the bottom pane needs to cover the whole screen but what about tablet apps, is it the same?

**Current design:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.The 4 icons added on the bottom left can be moved to right top next to the search
  bar as you have some space o'er there and also the left pane as a whole can be 
  used for the preview(the client's req, as you have specified).

2.There are no particular conventions unless the user is satisfied with the positions where you provide the options (as conventions change and the change sets a trend).

3. The user here either can drag and drop or click over the image to get the preview of it unless you provide let the user know that he/she has an option to drag and drop (which either can be textual or a tour when they open this page for the first time)

I guess the above could change the view a bit. Proper space management will help you to show things in a better way to the user. Hope this helps.